# Validating if user input is already sanitised

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've been working on a mini project with Python3 and tkinter recently that is used to sanitise URLs and IP addresses. I've hit a roadblock with my function that I cannot workout. What I am trying to achieve is:

- Has a user entered a URL such as http://www.google.com or https://www.google.com and if so, sanitise as:

hxxp[:]//www[.]google[.]com or hxxps[:]//www[.]google[.]com

- Has a user entered an IP address such as 192.168.1.1 or http://192.168.1.1 and sanitise as:

192[.]168[.]1[.]1 or hxxp[:]//192[.]168[.]1[.]1

- Has a user entered already sanitised input? Is there unsanitised input along with it? If so, just sanitise the unsanitised input and print them to the results output Textbox.

I have included a screenshot of what is currently happening to my normal input, after input is sanitised and how I want to handle the above issues.

Also: Is the .strip() in the OutputTextbox.insert line redundant?

I appreciate any help and recommendations!

```
def printOut():
    outputTextbox.delete("1.0", "end")
    url = inputTextbox.get("1.0", "end-1c")
 
    if len(url) == 0:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter content to sanitise")
 
    if "hxxp" and "[:]" and "[.]" in url or "hxxps" and "[:]" and "[.]" in url:
        outputTextbox.insert("1.0", url, "\n".strip())
        pass
 
    elif "http" and ":" and "." in url:
        url = url.replace("http", "hxxp")
        url = url.replace(":", "[:]")
        url = url.replace(".", "[.]")
        outputTextbox.insert("1.0", url, "\n".strip())
 
    elif "https" and ":" and "." in url:
        url = url.replace("https", "hxxps")
        url = url.replace(":", "[:]")
        url = url.replace(".", "[.]")
        outputTextbox.insert("1.0", url, "\n".strip())
 
    elif "http" and ":" and range(0, 10) and "." in url or range(0, 10) and "." in url:
        url = url.replace("http", "hxxp")
        url = url.replace(".", "[.]")
        outputTextbox.insert("1.0", url, "\n".strip())
```

[image: Normal Input being sanitised]

[image: Sanitised input along with unsanitised input]

[image: Wanted output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression like `A AND B AND C IN URL` will has result like `A AND B AND (C IN URL)`, not what you expect that `A`, `B`, `C` are all found in `URL`.

You can use `re` (regex module) to achieve what you want:

```py
import re

def printOut():
    outputTextbox.delete("1.0", "end")
    url = inputTextbox.get("1.0", "end-1c")

    if len(url) == 0:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter content to sanitise")

    result = url.replace("http", "hxxp")
    result = re.sub(r"([^\[]):([^\]])", r"\1[:]\2", result)
    result = re.sub(r"([^\[])\.([^\]])", r"\1[.]\2", result)

    outputTextbox.insert("end", result, "\n")
```

There may be better regex for that.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, this was exactly what I was trying to achieve. I have done some further testing, what I found was if a user enters a newline inbetween text I cannot remove it to clean it up for print results and saving to files

I cannot remove this newline space at all. I've read other stack questions and someone mentioned it cannot be removed using "end-1c". I'll do some further tests and see if i can clean this up, because when saving it looks messy and further work for users to clean up.